# Django: provide global method to all (class-based) views?

Tags: python, django, django-middleware, django-class-based-views

I need a button, included in the header of every page in my Django application, to trigger some global method, to toggle a "`mode`" setting in the session.  There are two modes: 'preview' and 'publish'.

One solution I've come up with: duplicate a `post()` method in every (class-based) view, to handle the mode change.  This hardly seems DRY.

Another would be to inherit all of my CBVs from a single superclass, or use a mixin.  I suppose this is a possibility.

A better solution perhaps: I've setup a `context_processor` to handle publishing the mode globally to my templates. This works fine. I've also setup a `middleware` class with `process_request` which could, theoretically, handle `POST` requests globally.  But how do I call this `process_request` method from my templates?

My current stab at it follows.  How do I toggle the "preview" and "publish" buttons in my template, and call the middleware?

**`template.html`**:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<header>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- button toggle -->
    {% if mode == 'preview' %}
        <button name="mode" value="publish">Publish</button>
    {% else %}
        <button name="mode" value="preview">Preview</button>
    {% endif %}
    </form>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

**`middleware.py`:**

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        update_mode(request)

def update_mode(request, new_mode=None): # how do I call this from template?
    modes = [
        'preview',
        'publish'
    ]

    # ensure default
    if not request.session.get('mode', None):
        request.session['mode'] = 'preview'

    # set new mode
    if new_mode and new_mode in modes:
        request.session['mode'] = new_mode
```

**`context_processor.py`:**

```
def template_mode(request):
    context = {
        'mode': request.session['mode']
    }
    return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "call" middleware: that's not at all how it works. Middleware is invoked on every request, so in your case the update_mode function would always run.

A better solution would be to get the form containing the button to post to a new URL, which invokes a view to update the mode. You could add a hidden field containing the current URL - which you can get from `request.path` - and the update mode view can redirect back to that URL after doing its work.

Comment: This is a great idea, thanks, I think this is just what I'm looking for.  Much simpler.  Do I always access the request from `post()` in this new view, then?
Also, is it normal to have a `UtilityView` or something to handle miscellaneous global requests like this?  Or do people tend to have multiple one-off utility views, one for each global function?

Comment: or, maybe this is a good excuse to use a function-based view again, for once

Comment: You can only have one `post` method per class, so you'd need multiple view classes. Personally I don't use class-based views much, I'd just have several individual views functions.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it that way - how about making a template tag for the form?

In your templatetags.py:

```
def set_session_mode_form():
    return {'session_form': SessionForm()}

register.inclusion)tag("<path-to-your-template>",set_session_mode_form)
```

Then your session form sends to a view that updates the session variable you want.
To use it, just load the tags on your page and use {% include %}. This way, its very easy to add to any page, and keeps it DRY.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks.  I believe it basically recommends what @Daniel Roseman says in the other answer, though... send to a custom view which handles the variable.  I like the idea of a custom template tag, but it's maybe gravy in this case.